# Why don't the tcp server reply my syn packet when I try to connect it through raw socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpdump

It depends on the `iphdr.saddr` field.
When it was set to my own address or a random multicast address, I can see the server replied with the syn/ack packet.
If set to other ips, the server didn't reply.
How to explain it?

The multicast address case:

`13:55:08.242535 IP 240.151.224.61.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [S], seq 123456, win 4096, length 0
E..(g+..@......=....5..g...@....P...$X..
13:55:14.906511 IP 239.151.224.61.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [S], seq 123456, win 4096, length 0
E..(g+..@......=....5..g...@....P...%X..
13:55:14.906549 IP localhost.5223 > 239.151.224.61.13579: Flags [S.], seq 3502093187, ack 123457, win 43690, options [mss 65495], length 0
E..,..@.@..........=.g5........A`...N.......
13:55:15.904599 IP localhost.5223 > 239.151.224.61.13579: Flags [S.], seq 3502093187, ack 123457, win 43690, options [mss 65495], length 0

`

my own address case:

`14:14:22.989225 IP slave1.domain.com.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [S], seq 123456, win 4096, length 0
E..(g+..@......m....5..g...@....P...3...
14:14:22.989236 IP localhost.5223 > slave1.domain.com.13579: Flags [S.], seq 3228604881, ack 123457, win 43690, options [mss 65495], length 0
E..,..@.@..........m.g5..p.....A`...A5......
14:14:22.989259 IP slave1.domain.com.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [.], ack 3228604882, win 4096, length 0
E..(..@.@......m....5..g...A.p..P.......
`

no syn/ack reply case:

`14:16:18.719629 IP 223.151.224.61.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [S], seq 123456, win 4096, length 0
E..(g+..@......=....5..g...@....P...5X..
14:16:46.511299 IP 240.151.224.61.13579 > localhost.5223: Flags [S], seq 123456, win 4096, length 0
E..(g+..@......=....5..g...@....P...$X..`

Answer (score 0):

`iphdr.saddr` represents the source address of the IP packet. I assume that the receiving end of your `SYN` packet will try to respond with an `ACK` to whatever source address you provide in the IP packet.

Comment: The server didn't reply me unless `iphdr.saddr` was set to a multicast type address